# Simplify a perl script

Tags: perl, text-files

I am debugging a **done-by-another-one** script.

This is the snippet he did:

```
 ...
open OUTPUT_FILE, "$makingOutDir/$inputFile";
$_ = <OUTPUT_FILE>;
while ( defined($_) ) {
  $diff_text .= prep_for_output($_);
  $_ = <OUTPUT_FILE>;
}
close OUTPUT_FILE;

print <<EOF
Test $num_test skipped: missing output file for matching
$diff_text
EOF
 ...
```

I was wondering if is it possible to obtain the same behavior simplifying it doing like this:

```
 ...
print "Test $num_test skipped: missing output file for matching";
open OUTPUT_FILE, catfile($makingOutDir, $inputFile) or die $!;
while ( <OUTPUT_FILE> ) {
  my $diff = prep_for_output($_);

  print <<EOF
$diff
EOF
}
close OUTPUT_FILE;
 ...
```

or, in your opinions, there are a better and simpler way?

Comment: First code with `while` clearly falls into OMFG category.

Comment: @mpapec so, first code is *bad*. Second is *passable*. Do you suggest a third way, or the best that one could do is second?

Comment: Third would be NOT accumulating output into `$diff_text` but outputting it right away. If this wrote some of your colleagues tell him that such level of competence is expected from someone dealing with perl less than a week.

Comment: Yes, something in that manner.

Comment: You don't have to use a heredoc to print, you can just `print $diff` (assuming newlines are handled by `prep_for_output`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a massive improvement, but something like this, perhaps.

```
print "Test $num_test skipped: missing output file for matching";

my $filename = catfile($makingOutDir, $inputFile);
open my $out_fh, '<', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";

print prep_for_output($_) while <$out_fh>;

close $out_fh;
```